# Passing Function as parameter in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, higher-order-functions, function-parameter

I am trying to make a function to calculate rolling mean or sum :

```
def rolling_lag_creator(dataset,i,func):  
    dataset['Bid']=dataset.loc[:,'Bid'].rolling(window=i).func()
    return dataset
```

but this function is throwing error when i am calling this:

```
rolling_lag_creator(Hypothesis_ADS,5,mean)
```

Error:

```
NameError: name 'mean' is not defined
```

while below code works fine:

```
dataset['Bid']=dataset.loc[:,'Bid'].rolling(window=5).mean()
```

Can anyone help me how to call such methods as parameters, thank you.

Comment: The error message is telling you “name ‘mean’ is not defined’.  You need to define the function `mean`. Or refer to an existing function `mean()`

Comment: Rolling function return is rolling object and is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mean` is a *method*, not a function per se. And anyway, attribute access doesn't work like that, but you can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr), something like this:

```
def rolling_lag_creator(dataset, i, method_name):
    method = getattr(dataset.loc[:,'Bid'].rolling(window=i), method_name)
    dataset['Bid'] = method()
    return dataset

rolling_lag_creator(Hypothesis_ADS, 5, 'mean')
```

Comment: Waao , thanks your answer works flawlessly , this is what i needed thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to:

```
import numpy as np
```

and then replace `mean` with `np.mean`